# Clip a GeoTIFF with a shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, geotiff-tiff, clip

I have a geotiff file that I made in Python. After I created it, I realized it was for all of North America, and I only need the United States. I then got what I assumed was a shapefile of the US border, and tried to clip with

`gdalwarp -cutline shapefile.shp input.tif output.tif`

When I do this, it creates an output file, but the whole file is filled with zeros. I have tried a few other methods, but they all end up being filled with zeros. I think it could have to do with the spatial reference or the extent of either the shp or tif. Anyone have any ideas? Files included below.

[Here is the geotiff file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8tu6sohgCxaSkkzZk16NkdGOVU/view?usp=sharing)

[Here is the shapefile.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8tu6sohgCxaN093T2dOMmRkd0E/view?usp=sharing)

I have also tried a different shapefile, but that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just link to a .shp file, you need to have all the [components](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) of the shapefile ,in a zip file preferably (.shp, .dbf, .shx, and in this case .prj) for us to help. From your download you have only have the .shp but this is okay as I recognize the name of your shapefile from the census (from the download file).

This is why you get nothing, nothing is under the USA polygon.

[image]

They do not align.

You shapefile is fine but your Geotiff has florida at ~57 degrees north, it is closer to 27 degrees north.

The envelope information is incorrect. Time to go back to your tiff creation process in Python with a view to registration.

Comment: I only included the shapefile, but I have all the other files in the same directory. And interesting. Whats the best method to get them to match up?

Comment: It is all on the tiff, you need to go back to the source of this and how you created it. Or GDAL Warp.

Comment: Thanks. It was just a small error in the python code. I was using ```geotransform=(xmin, xres, 0, ymax, 0, yres)``` and my ```yres``` was suppose to be negative.

Comment: Yes that looks like it, , this is my best effort but I did not have the precise info to fix so use yours... but here it is just in case. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5XlZJJ2R5taU4xMkFDRTJQU0k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Yeah, no problem. My fix made it work. Thanks for your help!